# Match the end of a SQL FROM clause with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm modifying a SQL view from some C# code. The view pulls data from a table that has a date at the end like so:

```
SELECT ...
FROM DAILY_TABLE_190801
WHERE ...
```

I'd like to pick out just the date part so that I can change it like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM DAILY_TABLE_190802
WHERE ...
```

The only thing I could come up with was this expression with a lookbehind:

```
(?<=FROM.+)[0-9]{6}
```

but that does not work since regular expressions inside lookbehinds are not allowed.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: *regular expressions inside lookbehinds are not allowed* - really? [**Your regex works**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dFROM.%2b%29%5b0-9%5d%7b6%7d&i=SELECT+...%0d%0aFROM+DAILY_TABLE_190801%0d%0aWHERE+...). Have you attempted to write the C# code using this regex? You would see it is working.

Comment: You're absolutely right! My application has a bit of a cumbersome build procedure so I've been testing this with Sublime Text's regex engine where it didn't work. I found this: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html which states that most flavors of regex do not support regex inside lookbehind but I guess C# does!

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](https://regex101.com/r/coTcDr/2)

```
^FROM (.+?(\d+))\s*$
```

should be enough, if SQL queries look like you posted.
First group matches full table name, second (nested) matches decimal part of the name and `\s` matches zero or more whitespace characters until end of line.

Comment: This matches the whole FROM clause. I need to match just the digits at the end. In any case it turns out that the regex engine c# uses supports regex inside lookbehinds

Comment: @jbb I think my version is more efficient, but you can stick to the solution you like the best. BTW You can use Match.Groups[2] to get onlynumber in my case (if it is what you want)

Comment: I didn't know that you could pick just Match Group 2 like that. Doing that solves this for me but as per Wiktor Stribiżew's comment the lookbehind actually does work in C# and that is in my opinion a slightly neater solution. If you can find a solution that does not require a regex inside of a lookbehind, then that would not be a c# specific solution and that would definitely be a better solution :)